# I've created a Blazor Web Assembly App with a HttpGet request, which works locally but fails once published to Azure

Tags: azure, blazor

I've created a Blazor web assembly app with a Httpget request. It runs fine locally, but when publish to an Azure App Service as ASP.NET hosted the Httpget request fails with this error:

> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '<' is an invalid start of a
>   value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0. at
>   System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException
>   (System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader& json,
>   System.Text.Json.ExceptionResource resource, System.Byte nextByte,
>   System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] bytes) <0x2a486d8 + 0x00020> in
>   <515164c3ada14b86914aa92e915c4401>:0 at
>   System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue (System.Byte marker)
>   <0x2682800 + 0x00260> in <515164c3ada14b86914aa92e915c4401>:0 at
>   System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken (System.Byte first)
>   <0x2681ad8 + 0x001ae> in <515164c3ada14b86914aa92e915c4401>:0 at
>   System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment () <0x26814d0 +
>   0x001fe> in <515164c3ada14b86914aa92e915c4401>:0 at
>   System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read () <0x2681098 + 0x0000e> in
>   <515164c3ada14b86914aa92e915c4401>:0 at
>   System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore
>   (System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options,
>   System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader& reader, System.Text.Json.ReadStack&
>   readStack) <0x2680a20 + 0x0005e> in
>   <515164c3ada14b86914aa92e915c4401>:0

// Create my data in a list

```
public class ConfiguratorRepo
{
        public List<Configurator> GetConfigurators()
        {
            Configurator Icfs = new Configurator
            {
                Name = "My test",
                ID = 99,
                Description = "Desc"
            };

            List<Configurator> Icf = new List<Configurator>
            {
                Icfs
            };

            return Icf;
        }
}
```

// Set up HttpGet

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ConfiguratorController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetAll")]
    public IList<Configurator> Get()
    {
        ConfiguratorRepo repo = new ConfiguratorRepo();

        return repo.GetConfigurators(); 
    }
}
```

//Within the code section in my .razor page

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            Configurators = await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<Configurator>>("Configurator/GetAll");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Error = e.InnerException.ToString();
        }

    }
```

This is a link to the project https://1drv.ms/u/s!As_wHGs2IYp0kgsfcf970zD53Vvt?e=mnPrph

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Check the HTTP response, it doesn't look to be json

Comment: I've since realised this may be nothing to do with the code, it may be setup problem in Azure or a bug. The FetchData for weather data within the supplied template also errors in the same way.

Comment: The error is because the input is html passed from the server notifying you of some issues, but the json reader cannot process the received data. I'd suggest you first check if the url to the web API end point is correct and complete. CORS issues may also be related. If you could fish the complete text passed to the json reader; that is, before it is processed by the reader, you may be able to read the Html string, and get some idea what is the issue.

Comment: I've used Postman to see what is returned by the Http Get request and I can see the HTML for the page is returned instead of the expected JSON. This explains the '<' in the error. I assume this is happening because when I deploy to Azure the Http GET is not allowed for some reason. I've tried using Kudu in Azure to amend the web.config to allow Http GET but this has no effect. There must be a setting in Azure somewhere I'm missing.